# Regular Expression to validate short and long date in mm/dd/yyyy format in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

I wanna validate date which can be either in short date format or long date format.
eg: for some of the valid date.

12/05/2010 , 12/05/10 , 12-05-10, 12-05-2010

```
var reLong = /\b\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}\b/;
var reShort = /\b\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2}\b/;
var valid = (reLong.test(entry)) || (reShort.test(entry));
if(valid)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

but this current regular expression fails when i try to give an invalid date as 12/05/20-0

Comment: codeddict's right. You BTW might be able to combine the 2 Regex togeter into one: ^\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-](\d{2}|\d{4})$... and the first digit of mm could be optimized further as well - Depends on what you'd like to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `12/05/20` which is a substring of your input `12/05/20-0` is a valid date.

To avoid substring matches you can use anchors as:

```
/^\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}$/
```

But again the above allows dates such as `00/00/0000` and `29/02/NON_LEAP_YEAR` which are invalid.

So its better to use a library function do this validation.

I was able to find one such library: [datajs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly more robust regex that will attempt to filter out some bad dates:

```
^(1[012]|0[1-9])([\/\-])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\2((?:19|20)?\d{2})$
```

Input (as seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/3Tuo0UIjxn))

```
01/01/2001  # valid
10-10-10    # valid
09/09/1998  # valid
00-00-0000  # invalid
15-15-2000  # invalid
```

Day matches: 01 to 31, month matches: 01-12 and year matches 1900-2099. It will also force you to enter a consistent separator (ie: `mm/dd/yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy` work, but `mm-dd/yyyy` doesn't).

This will still take some bad dates (such as 02/30/2000), but for practical purposes it should be good enough. This will also put month, day and year in capture groups 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Comment: will this validate both short and long dates?