# Regular expression for MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to validate short and long date in mm/dd/yyyy format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827312/regular-expression-to-validate-short-and-long-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-javas)

I am using a regular expression `/^\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}$/` for validating MM/DD/YYYY in javascript.

But currently it will validate dates like 13/22/2012 , 10/45/2012.
How can i correct it.

Comment: you probably are better off using a library like [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Don't edit out the duplicate messages, please.

Comment: @Linto the page you dismiss as being a duplicate has another suggestion on it to filter out bad dates. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the regular expressions and simply use [`split()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

> Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

Once you have each part of the date separately, you'll be able to validate it using simple conditional statements.

```
var dateStr = "MM/DD/YYYY";
var dateParts = str.split('/');  // ["MM", "DD", "YYYY"]
```

Bear in mind that any validation done with JavaScript on the client side should not be trusted! Any user can get in there and manipulate your JavaScript. You should always implement validation on the server side as well. Usually client side validation is more of a user experience thing...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a library to achieve this, don't reinvent the wheel. One of the most popular is jquery UI datepicker, which provides also a nice popup calendar to choose dates.

Comment: jQuery UI datepicker does **not** "validate" dates. Sure it allows picking valid dates, but it doesn't prevent you from entering invalid date formats. Of course validation must be done in the back end but this doesn't answer the validation in JS question.